# data.frame column lengths are not equal

Tags: r

This is totally bizarre. I have a data frame of 20 columns and 200 rows. When I take the number of rows

```
nrow(df)
```

I get 200. But when I call some of the columns individually and take their length, say for example,

```
length(df$x3)
```

I get numbers slightly different from 200, such as 207, 203, etc. This is only for some of the columns, while the rest have length 200.

I created this data.frame by coercing a VectorSpaceModel object created using a word2vec model trained using the wordVectors package. Here is more or less what I did:

```
term_vec <- c("word1", "word2", "word3", ..., "word20")
properties <- model[[term_vec, average = F]]
df_prop <- as.data.frame(t(properties))
```

`df_prop` is then the data.frame with 20 cols and 200 rows, but whose cols have varying lengths when called separately.

EDIT:

```
str(df_prop)

'data.frame':   200 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ activ         : num  -0.02795 0.00135 0.25447 0.02538 -0.02762 ...
 $ protein       : num  -0.0374 -0.2037 0.1852 -0.229 0.0437 ...
 $ cancer        : num  -0.2043 0.0144 0.1125 0.0405 0.09 ...
 $ role          : num  -0.1164 -0.2313 -0.0207 0.1405 -0.1694 ...
 $ oncogen       : num  -0.19599 -0.0771 0.00398 0.06351 -0.1299 ...
 $ loss          : num  -0.17479 -0.4214 0.28711 -0.07563 -0.00643 ...
 $ missens       : num  -0.1502 -0.4113 -0.0141 -0.1355 -0.0793 ...
 $ recurr        : num  0.16952 -0.31017 -0.00389 -0.06503 -0.03874 ...
 $ driver        : num  0.1928 -0.1774 -0.1946 -0.2157 -0.0734 ...
 $ cbl           : num  0.0593 -0.4683 -0.0712 0.184 0.1519 ...
 $ gain          : num  0.128 -0.313 0.251 -0.135 0.101 ...
 $ neutral       : num  0.06243 0.10662 -0.24245 -0.00875 -0.06072 ...
 $ polymorph     : num  0.0526 -0.2005 0.1147 -0.2716 0.2272 ...
 $ deleteri      : num  0.0705 -0.1022 -0.289 0.1769 -0.0114 ...
 $ loh           : num  -0.0133 -0.533 0.2306 -0.0127 0.1488 ...
 $ switch        : num  -0.1088 0.0453 -0.1768 0.1646 0.0477 ...
 $ passeng       : num  0.4528 -0.3491 0.2232 -0.2857 -0.0531 ...
 $ inconclus     : num  0.56665 0.00575 0.10589 -0.09961 -0.00753 ...
 $ heterozygosity: num  -0.0212 -0.7096 0.4345 -0.0401 0.0158 ...
 $ q249e         : num  -0.382 -0.673 -0.153 0.145 -0.18 ...
```

But

```
length(df_prop$driver)
[1] 207

> linmod <- lm(passeng ~ neutral + driver, data = df_prop)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = passeng ~ neutral + driver, data = df_prop,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'driver')

> str(df_prop$driver)
 num [1:207] 0.1928 -0.1774 -0.1946 -0.2157 -0.0734 ...

> sapply(df_prop, class)
         activ        protein         cancer           role        oncogen           loss        missens         recurr 
     "numeric"      "numeric"      "numeric"      "numeric"      "numeric"      "numeric"      "numeric"      "numeric" 
        driver            cbl           gain        neutral      polymorph       deleteri            loh         switch 
     "numeric"      "numeric"      "numeric"      "numeric"      "numeric"      "numeric"      "numeric"      "numeric" 
       passeng      inconclus heterozygosity          q249e 
     "numeric"      "numeric"      "numeric"      "numeric" 

> length(df_prop$passeng)
[1] 204
> length(df_prop$neutral)
[1] 204
> length(df_prop$driver)
[1] 207
> dput(df_prop[c("passeng", "neutral", "driver")])
structure(list(passeng = c(0.452785223722458, -0.349059224128723, 
0.223233446478844, -0.285723477602005, -0.0530807785689831, -0.112091585993767, 
0.0916753336787224, -0.505712330341339, -0.0289060920476913, 
-0.0842016264796257, 0.338186889886856, 0.586610317230225, 0.216203600168228, 
0.410553187131882, 0.0717814415693283, -0.0429450906813145, -0.0296403076499701, 
-0.23951618373394, 0.159736976027489, -0.414268016815186, 0.0648640096187592, 
-0.0192434135824442, -0.0520854219794273, 0.133157446980476, 
-0.00781008694320917, 0.0803053453564644, 0.04029206559062, -0.227307245135307, 
-0.34715148806572, 0.0180112048983574, 0.0419463403522968, -0.287112087011337, 
-0.103216387331486, -0.00813597533851862, -0.473377019166946, 
0.02095066010952, -0.0118085974827409, 0.0805344358086586, -0.0890048146247864, 
-0.0509019605815411, 0.0337137281894684, -0.140259340405464, 
-0.164335578680038, 0.0143457390367985, -0.421713650226593, -0.350066483020782, 
0.256413668394089, -0.262221038341522, 0.125508412718773, -0.1669010668993, 
-0.323957771062851, 0.121560901403427, 0.0398254878818989, -0.127609387040138, 
-0.348305493593216, -0.59373140335083, -0.43903249502182, 0.018520962446928, 
0.201807394623756, -0.444083839654922, 0.200975254178047, -0.301672697067261, 
0.230098724365234, 0.0907209143042564, 0.0885164812207222, 0.0177833493798971, 
-0.0124702183529735, -0.0641361474990845, -0.0831363871693611, 
-0.19027952849865, -0.166728913784027, 0.0293176043778658, 0.142488345503807, 
0.319564342498779, 0.0564890131354332, 0.0332652218639851, 0.0741571933031082, 
-0.0815279185771942, 0.0147021086886525, 0.077141061425209, -0.177572771906853, 
0.0499499812722206, -0.0831519737839699, 0.112121917307377, -0.103135667741299, 
-0.353338032960892, 0.15715280175209, -0.125472351908684, -0.144316121935844, 
-0.223944634199142, 0.0473198145627975, -0.285173535346985, -0.091559074819088, 
-0.23955462872982, -0.135925456881523, 0.106332272291183, 0.3387231528759, 
-0.230065390467644, -0.0370972417294979, -0.267686247825623, 
0.0271094776690006, -0.263466387987137, -0.124173454940319, -0.129989266395569, 
0.0639095827937126, 0.0804392695426941, -0.205364063382149, 0.34429532289505, 
-0.239175975322723, 0.521911144256592, -0.0506611131131649, 0.0372519791126251, 
-0.110514439642429, 0.0399324893951416, -0.0326474010944366, 
0.0534966289997101, -0.336249321699142, 0.0687438398599625, -0.0149638978764415, 
-0.079196035861969, 0.0412308536469936, -0.168989613652229, 0.426938116550446, 
0.108011208474636, 0.356941521167755, -0.35343012213707, 0.208558425307274, 
-0.0620005242526531, 0.13456092774868, -0.214266702532768, -0.314923346042633, 
-0.0311665218323469, -0.192426383495331, 0.103004567325115, -0.119352847337723, 
0.0841932892799377, -0.0218736603856087, -0.178017675876617, 
-0.124427333474159, 0.233909919857979, 0.0559673868119717, -0.104320652782917, 
0.296732783317566, -0.19652085006237, 0.28268176317215, 0.118357747793198, 
0.324692904949188, 0.173546448349953, 0.119432643055916, -0.0791224911808968, 
0.119982831180096, -0.141497865319252, -0.191946685314178, 0.154124990105629, 
0.185841098427773, -0.147911578416824, 0.408693969249725, 0.151209264993668, 
-0.432886987924576, 0.00650644721463323, -0.315581798553467, 
-0.247532770037651, 0.143373981118202, -0.364778310060501, 0.226706951856613, 
0.0187635440379381, -0.0128085305914283, -0.116108402609825, 
-0.203655496239662, -0.063552051782608, 0.0922449454665184, -0.371555089950562, 
-0.143712520599365, 0.323709845542908, -0.0827256366610527, 0.10759025067091, 
0.342874735593796, -0.266680926084518, 0.24025596678257, 0.35177743434906, 
0.00122027634643018, 0.320188760757446, 0.180638343095779, 0.204436093568802, 
-0.049614429473877, -0.0895709544420242, -0.0814719721674919, 
0.000497184810228646, 0.15266053378582, 0.243941411375999, 0.0695823654532433, 
-0.0984447300434113, 0.156076744198799, 0.40799942612648, -0.359382539987564, 
-0.0958247110247612, -0.063414603471756, -0.492347091436386, 
-0.212932005524635, -0.399490386247635, 0.452785223722458, -0.349059224128723, 
0.223233446478844, -0.285723477602005), neutral = c(0.0624283887445927, 
0.106615483760834, -0.242450177669525, -0.00875413231551647, 
-0.0607167445123196, -0.0874784588813782, 0.0159694887697697, 
-0.310035288333893, -0.470642864704132, 0.312223583459854, -0.0133906025439501, 
0.456694394350052, 0.327305197715759, -0.0492987744510174, -0.327871382236481, 
0.0123024489730597, -0.112976022064686, -0.183681637048721, 0.0786364153027534, 
-0.0556268356740475, 0.0593749359250069, 0.308130115270615, 0.0545936934649944, 
0.0112099116668105, 0.195658937096596, -0.0926103219389915, 0.131353974342346, 
0.36189866065979, -0.310230076313019, -0.0959832593798637, 0.0129279075190425, 
0.0170739497989416, -0.212557435035706, -0.10607548803091, 0.0198365785181522, 
-0.0790213569998741, 0.233813554048538, 0.0603582486510277, 0.0574430525302887, 
-0.0025249389000237, 0.178253039717674, -0.161745145916939, -0.0651656538248062, 
0.0898096263408661, -0.199210107326508, 0.345266789197922, -0.0608342587947845, 
-0.0240304097533226, -0.059606347233057, 0.237234279513359, -0.182934284210205, 
-0.0805316418409348, 0.477729558944702, 0.355416506528854, -0.195008412003517, 
-0.285221040248871, -0.275740891695023, -0.0590328797698021, 
0.00807524751871824, -0.181720346212387, 0.133480831980705, -0.0923505499958992, 
0.319016247987747, 0.310231000185013, 0.0212804675102234, -0.158257618546486, 
-0.00906388554722071, 0.133870497345924, 0.163518846035004, 0.159345477819443, 
0.00162855989765376, -0.244596600532532, 0.265527069568634, -0.0766861364245415, 
0.071528285741806, 0.200394779443741, -0.0659522116184235, -0.0894035324454308, 
0.386227011680603, 0.155652150511742, 0.206601455807686, -0.34688338637352, 
0.103099264204502, 0.336126208305359, -0.109791465103626, 0.025560649111867, 
0.18004846572876, 0.0455960370600224, 0.129409417510033, -0.0663190484046936, 
-0.0694380551576614, 0.269877940416336, 0.123965159058571, 0.208219081163406, 
-0.0259098093956709, 0.0244570504873991, -0.0531765818595886, 
-0.224155947566032, -0.115240715444088, 0.0962978675961494, 0.157494246959686, 
0.00240525603294373, -0.0600106082856655, 0.167411848902702, 
-0.00585554260760546, 0.0355127118527889, -0.196092844009399, 
-0.0188772100955248, -0.151142120361328, -0.200211212038994, 
-0.0215719062834978, 0.0169646516442299, -0.16918058693409, -0.0534995049238205, 
0.143689811229706, 0.0359412282705307, 0.279378980398178, 0.258504390716553, 
-0.074554406106472, 0.335559964179993, 0.263022631406784, 0.197986051440239, 
-0.138966783881187, 0.195296406745911, 0.143159613013268, -0.148128971457481, 
0.3902488052845, -0.345333695411682, -0.134910404682159, 0.135866537690163, 
0.278762727975845, 0.118465282022953, -0.22791101038456, -0.154258042573929, 
-0.152354970574379, 0.0967835634946823, 0.476795643568039, -0.575522124767303, 
-0.1163110435009, 0.173384621739388, -0.249152660369873, -0.110836043953896, 
-0.120327040553093, 0.123326189815998, 0.036122415214777, 0.0511444658041, 
0.101496443152428, 0.142479866743088, 0.0739700049161911, -0.101869978010654, 
0.0706672668457031, -0.0612174309790134, 0.208535611629486, 0.0153503911569715, 
-0.121934145689011, -0.0994135960936546, 0.301655441522598, -0.117937028408051, 
-0.467048764228821, -0.126288637518883, -0.263451159000397, 0.164172038435936, 
0.365282714366913, 0.216561645269394, 0.185734942555428, 0.199943736195564, 
0.126512348651886, -0.072352223098278, 0.129932269454002, 0.309069633483887, 
0.000678401032928377, -0.00318608805537224, 0.136844977736473, 
0.366614729166031, -0.326217412948608, 0.0876872763037682, -0.0637753307819366, 
0.112328112125397, -0.392527550458908, 0.0157560463994741, 0.0637902021408081, 
-0.15483346581459, 0.0630035400390625, 0.167358994483948, 0.226734787225723, 
0.0888303220272064, 0.0440737493336201, 0.107901841402054, -0.115406967699528, 
-0.0672288686037064, -0.0101721612736583, -0.110640466213226, 
-0.24146357178688, 0.113892689347267, 0.108142912387848, -0.239095509052277, 
-0.0326027497649193, 0.144274324178696, -0.0831330195069313, 
-0.0282934606075287, 0.0624283887445927, 0.106615483760834, -0.242450177669525, 
-0.00875413231551647), driver = c(0.192841440439224, -0.177443191409111, 
-0.194590926170349, -0.215662553906441, -0.073422372341156, -0.249199375510216, 
0.336783885955811, -0.247152045369148, 0.0759363397955894, 0.202224016189575, 
0.0579937845468521, -0.0315181687474251, -0.268824219703674, 
0.163264974951744, 0.320090681314468, 0.0288974922150373, 0.00578439189121127, 
-0.238630563020706, 0.263456761837006, -0.326677918434143, 0.0100676929578185, 
0.186660930514336, 0.0529752001166344, 0.172556579113007, 0.0344753190875053, 
-0.0375318937003613, 0.090083159506321, -0.202253371477127, -0.15420438349247, 
-0.0356156565248966, 0.196105360984802, -0.0992875695228577, 
-0.0626049414277077, -0.0435837954282761, -0.12100450694561, 
-0.010941019281745, 0.27052915096283, -0.0454284884035587, -0.269113779067993, 
-0.065261498093605, 0.180837854743004, 0.0523905120790005, 0.147859752178192, 
-0.0145671898499131, -0.438302397727966, -0.237480729818344, 
-0.13623084127903, 0.0325649604201317, -0.0994360595941544, -0.2902792096138, 
-0.437496393918991, -0.0240569356828928, 0.170194000005722, -0.105672776699066, 
-0.0963042005896568, -0.329953551292419, -0.389930844306946, 
-0.0327115058898926, -0.233221232891083, -0.0197642371058464, 
0.273058503866196, -0.389816999435425, 0.00940189696848392, -0.00786798354238272, 
0.172658368945122, 0.0880637839436531, 0.022097198292613, 0.129856511950493, 
0.180789142847061, -0.260635018348694, 0.00472282106056809, 0.107697121798992, 
0.106692224740982, 0.194839581847191, 0.238379791378975, 0.00421210564672947, 
-0.169722050428391, -0.131127566099167, -0.114339262247086, -0.0567750222980976, 
-0.129207447171211, 0.0325682610273361, -0.0426204539835453, 
0.285478800535202, 0.0624793395400047, -0.329177767038345, -0.183537155389786, 
0.0478714108467102, -0.527256846427917, 0.208344429731369, -0.223630920052528, 
-0.189286127686501, 0.138937622308731, 0.0905347689986229, -0.422364205121994, 
-0.14398404955864, -0.00858693942427635, -0.0884147360920906, 
0.226146027445793, -0.210005864500999, 0.0122118107974529, -0.268835186958313, 
0.0258086826652288, -0.0687210634350777, -0.0857537835836411, 
-0.135309383273125, -0.105474129319191, 0.293376386165619, -0.136220842599869, 
-0.0430038720369339, 0.110145010054111, 0.408281266689301, -0.198951378464699, 
-0.123419873416424, 0.0606197938323021, -0.0718433782458305, 
0.237005949020386, 0.0853797197341919, -0.0541917011141777, -0.00938241742551327, 
0.0353678315877914, -0.230596140027046, 0.110361091792583, 0.161412462592125, 
0.085545040667057, -0.12790310382843, -0.13336968421936, 0.17795641720295, 
0.0733387023210526, -0.308348536491394, -0.181677877902985, 0.101970627903938, 
0.0291164517402649, -0.0242572482675314, -0.236937135457993, 
-0.0996431559324265, 0.0395178869366646, -0.315638035535812, 
0.133494392037392, 0.162245228886604, 0.173758044838905, -0.0769962817430496, 
0.0964652448892593, -0.182265087962151, 0.0921082720160484, 0.153241410851479, 
0.362468242645264, 0.306828439235687, 0.0799067765474319, 0.0426596254110336, 
0.303493797779083, -0.165668562054634, -0.0794251933693886, 0.327983409166336, 
-0.0429684445261955, -0.0296640377491713, 0.0362571738660336, 
-0.0495377406477928, -0.0970798581838608, -0.0806222558021545, 
-0.452878385782242, -0.161120310425758, 0.233113989233971, -0.190250247716904, 
-0.0330471470952034, 0.302920013666153, 0.14268185198307, -0.114068612456322, 
-0.31039759516716, -0.225921854376793, 0.205708786845207, -0.319309294223785, 
-0.308616161346436, 0.168272659182549, -0.0735112801194191, 0.112985752522945, 
0.0841426774859428, -0.363907188177109, -0.0197736043483019, 
0.0447185151278973, -0.00954608619213104, 0.100676394999027, 
0.143523827195168, -0.07918681204319, -0.109777048230171, -0.17021943628788, 
-0.0855320245027542, -0.144370004534721, -0.0573471039533615, 
-0.0151970209553838, 0.233068540692329, -0.198467314243317, 0.154547318816185, 
0.332190752029419, -0.402606934309006, 0.1740802526474, 0.194449007511139, 
0.115612171590328, 0.266910642385483, -0.311915367841721, 0.192841440439224, 
-0.177443191409111, -0.194590926170349, -0.215662553906441, -0.073422372341156, 
-0.249199375510216, 0.336783885955811)), .Names = c("passeng", 
"neutral", "driver"), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Probably the output of `str(df)` will contain the answer.

Comment: yeah, try str(max.level = 3). My guess is that this is a list. Dataframes by definition cannot have atomic vectors of unequal length.

Comment: For completeness, could you add the output of `str(df_prop$driver)` as well?

Comment: you can also do this, to check the class of every column: `sapply(df_prop, class)`

Comment: @joran Added your suggested edit.

Comment: Now I'm curious.  Could you run `dput(df_prop)` and paste the output to your question?

Comment: @Benjamin You read my mind! ;) It'd be fine to knock the data frame down to only a handful of columns that still exhibit the behavior, to reduce the size of the `dput` output.

Comment: So maybe `dput(df_prop[c("passeng", "neutral", "driver")])` since these demonstrably failed in `lm`.

Comment: @Benjamin Done.

Comment: If you print the data frame, the warning `corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs` is displayed.  After searching that warning, I came up with this e-mail thread on the Rd-mailing-list. https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2005-February/032187.html. It seems that you attempted to do a replacement function on a column that did not exist.  (maybe?)

Comment: What version of R are you using? `R.Version()$version.string`

Comment: @Benjamin I don't get any "corrupt data.frame" message when I do print(df_prop), and as far as I know I didn't do anything like what happened in the referenced email string. My r version is > R.Version()$version.string
[1] "R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)"

Comment: I can recreate this sort of behavior in 3.3.2 by over-writing the row names attribute of a data frame to something shorter than the number of rows.

Comment: @Benjamin Aha, I think I got it. It has to do with the VectorSpaceModel-ness of the original "properties" object. To coerce it to data.frame have to do this: df_prop <- as.data.frame(t(properties@.Data))

Comment: Oh.  you were just using the wrong object slot.  That just go so much less interesting :D.  But glad you figured it out.

Comment: Though I suspect this is related to what @joran found.  As of R 3.2.4 "`as.data.frame.vector(*, row.names=*)` no longer produces ‘corrupted’ data frames from row names of incorrect length, but rather warns about them. This will become an error." By trying to transpose the `properties` object, instead of the `.Data` slot, the result got corrupted since you weren't working with a matrix-like object.

Comment: Can you writing down `dim(df)`?